# Wicket JavaScript browser compatibility

Tags: wicket

I am new to [Wicket](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Wicket), I have seen that it has Ajax related components.
When it generates JavaScript at the client side, is this JavaScript code cross-browser compatible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wicket Ajax's capabilities have been rated A (cross browser compatible) in [this article](http://www.musingsfrommars.org/2006/03/ajax-dhtml-library-scorecard.html). Although a bit outdated, it still remains true.

Don't forget that you can also integrate [jQuery](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JQuery), [Script.aculo.us](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Script.aculo.us) or any of the other "big" JavaScript libraries with Wicket.